# Converting MongoDB documents containing arrays of ISODates to Strings

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, bson, isodate

I have MongoDB documents of this form, where "vaccinations" is an array of ISODates:

```
{        
        "vacNo" : 1,
        "claimantDetails" : {
                "forename" : "Fry",
                "surname" : "Gordon",
                "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("2000-12-31T00:00:00Z")
        },
        "vaccinations" : [
                {
                        "dateOfVaccination" : ISODate("2010-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
                        "Type" : "MMR"
                },
                {
                        "dateOfVaccination" : ISODate("2015-01-31T00:00:00Z"),
                        "Type" : "Flu"
                }
        ]
}
```

I need to convert all ISODates to a string, including those in the "vaccinations" array (keeping the other fields as is) as below:

```
{
        "vacNo" : 1,
        "claimantDetails" : {
                "forename" : "Fry",
                "surname" : "Gordon",
                "dateOfBirth" : "2000-12-31"
        },
        "vaccinations" : [
                {
                        "dateOfVaccination" : "2010-12-31",
                        "Type" : "MMR"
                },
                {
                        "dateOfVaccination" : "2015-01-31",
                        "Type" : "Flu"
                }
        ]
}
```

I can use $dateToString but only on the fields which are not part of an array, such as:

```
db.claimTest.aggregate([{$project:{ _id:0, 
    "vacNo":1, 
    "claimantDetails.forename":1,
    "claimantDetails.surname":1,
    "claimantDetails.dateOfBirth":{ $dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d", date:"$claimantDetails.dateOfBirth"}}}}]);
```

which converts "claimantDetails.dateOfBirth" to a string, but I am unable to convert any of the "dateOfVaccination"s fields because they are  part of the "vaccinations" BSON array.

Does anyone have any suggestions/solutions which can help convert the ISODate document to the required document?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$map` to modify each element of an array. With the help of [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/), the following is one of the solutions,

```
db.claimTest.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "vacNo": 1,
        "claimantDetails.forename": 1,
        "claimantDetails.surname": 1,
        "claimantDetails.dateOfBirth":{ $dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d", date:"$claimantDetails.dateOfBirth"}},
        "vaccinations": {
            $map: {
                input: "$vaccinations",
                as: "v",
                in: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                        '$$v',
                        {
                            dateOfVaccination: {
                                $dateToString: {
                                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                                    date: "$$v.dateOfVaccination"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Edit: Corrected output

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly using $map & $mergeObjects

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow @Mustaq.  Feel free to upvote his answer and check it as correct so others can find this